Getting a console error when using Convex in NextJs
Getting this error when I wrap  inside .
[ Server ]  Error: Route "/" used headers().get('Host'). headers() should be awaited before using its value. Learn more: Nextjs
layout.tsx
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <ConvexAuthNextjsServerProvider>
      <html lang="en">
        <body>
          <JotaiProvider>
            {children}
          </JotaiProvider>
        </body>
      </html>
    </ConvexAuthNextjsServerProvider>
  );
}

Basically its saying that headers is a dynamic api and it should be called asynchronously. It was working in Nextjs14 but not now in 15 it is. Although I can still work on the project but this error comes up in console every time I refresh or open it. The official documentation of convex is also not updated yet

if you are using clerk then add dynamic in the clerkprovider>convexproviderwithclerk basically showing while using useAuth

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
